# How to add a img in a text field value

Tags: html, input

I wanna show a picture inside the default value of a text field. this is what I've tried but it doesn't work.

```
<input type="text" value="<img src="../images/left_arrow.gif" />Word" />
```

I've tried escaping the " but that doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to put the image as the background of the element..

**html**

```
<input type="text" class="with-default" value="Word" />
```

**css**

```
input.with-default{
   background: url('../images/left_arrow.gif') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you are flexible about the actual arrow appearance, you could use a unicode char to display the arrow i.e. ⇐

for more unicode arrows: http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/arrows.html

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6GyVM/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want a picture inside a text field? If it's just a decoration, use CSS background image.

Answer (score 0):

this is for asp.net

http://www.bitrepository.com/how-to-add-a-stylish-icon-into-a-form-text-box.html