# Inserting an img into a text field (html, css)

Tags: html, css

I have a text field and I want a small facebook icon inside or right next to that text field.

Here is some code for the text field and fb icon.  As it stands I have the text field and then the fb icon appears right below the text field to the right.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h6 class="section-header">NAME:</h6>
    <input class="form-control no-glow test-input" type="text" id="promocode" ng-model="review.promoCode" placeholder="start typing contact name">
    <img src="/img/facebook_btn.png" height="20" width="20" align="left" />
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h6 class="section-header">E-MAIL ADDRESS:</h6>
    <input class="form-control no-glow" type="text" id="promocode" ng-model="review.promoCode" placeholder="enter email addresses">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am new to html and css, so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: You'll have to provide relevant css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just needs some amendment to how you have setup your HTML and your alignments.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h6 class="section-header">NAME:</h6>
    <img src="/img/facebook_btn.png" height="20" width="20" align="left" />
    <input class="form-control no-glow test-input" type="text" id="promocode" ng-model="review.promoCode" placeholder="start typing contact name">
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h6 class="section-header">E-MAIL ADDRESS:</h6>
    <input class="form-control no-glow" type="text" id="promocode" ng-model="review.promoCode" placeholder="enter email addresses">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this helped.  I wanted it to the right of the field so I changed the align and adjusted the height and width of the fb img so got it exactly where I wanted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, you can do something what Bootstrap already provides, called `input-addons`:

```css
body {padding: 50px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-2">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give the input a class then set the img as a background image and give it some left side padding:

```
.className{
  background: url("/img/facebook_btn.png") no-repeat scroll 20px 20px;
  padding-left:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this question was already answered at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088830/how-to-add-a-img-in-a-text-field-value).
Basically, it should look like this:
**HTML**

```
<!-- This is your code-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h6 class="section-header">NAME:</h6>
      <input class="form-control no-glow test-input img-background" type="text" id="promocode" ng-model="review.promoCode" placeholder="start typing contact name">
       <!--Notice the class img-background given to the text field-->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input.img-background {
    background: url('/img/facebook_btn.png');
}
```

This should give your text field the Facebook image background.